# JPA 2.0 and ActiveMQ : Lazy loaded entity to send through object message

Tags: serialization, jpa, lazy-loading, activemq-classic

When I load an entity which contains lazy-loading fields and I want to send this entity through an object message with ActiveMQ, will I receive :

1. The full entity (with lazy-loading fields loaded)
   OR
2. The entity as sent (without lazy-loading fields loaded) ?

In any case do I need  to put the Serializable marker in my entity ?

In case of answer 1 what do I need to do to get the entity as described in answer 2 ?

Comment: the JMS object message is serialized "as-is", so you would get case 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have an entity with some lazy loading fields like this:

```
@Entity
public class Foo
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

When you receive this entity from your database only the `id` field will be loaded as the `bars` field is lazy loaded (`OneToMany` is lazy by default). Now when you pass this entity through JMS for example the `bars` field is not initialized because the `getBars()` method isn't called. When the remote end calls the getter it will get a `LazyInitializationException` as the entity is detached and the collection isn't initialized.

If you however want the remote end to be able to call the `getBars()` method you need to initialize the collection in some way. You can make the fetching of the collection eager using `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`. An alternative is to use a separate query for eager loading the entity (which is my personal preference).

Example:

```
select f from Foo f join fetch l.bars
```

If you really want to go wild and want the collection to be initialized lazily on the remote end you can take a look at Hibernate remote lazy loading using RMI. I'm not going to explain this because it seems out of the scope of the question. ;-)

Comment: I think that Petter and siebzOr have different points of view because I didn't precise in the description of the case that we assume that the lazy loading fields have not been loaded (e.g. the corresponding getters were not called). So as far as I understood, Petter has considered that the lazy loading fields have been initialized and siebzOr did not.
Thanks to both of you for your answers